# d3 (v4): giving elements the appearance of momentum?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

Suppose you want to have an html page where the entire background is an svg, such that there is some animation going on constantly. In this silly example, I have made a smiley face which randomly moves about. While some people might find brownian motion appealing to the eye, it would be nicer if the svg element could move with the appearance of momentum (both direction and rotation).

One might quickly realize that having an object move along a path would solve this issue and it would... for the first pass of the object. However if the element were to be bounded by the screen, then how could one get the transition to adjust for the deflection?

In short the question is as follows:

Using d3.js v4 how can I make an svg element (such as `#Mr_Smiley` in the demo below) appear to float* across the html page?

*let float mean smoothly move with constant velocity along a vector or arc within the svg space with recoil upon hitting borders and correct deflection

```js
var mr_s = d3.select("svg").append("g").attr("id", "Mr_Smiley")
mr_s.append("circle").attr("cx", 30).attr("cy", 30).attr("r", 30).style("fill","yellow").style("stroke", "black")
mr_s.append("circle").attr("cx", 20).attr("cy", 20).attr("r", 5).style("fill","black")
mr_s.append("circle").attr("cx", 40).attr("cy", 20).attr("r", 5).style("fill","black")
mr_s.append("path").attr("d", "M20 40 A 10 10 0 0 0 40 40").style("fill","black")


mr_s.datum({"x": 30, "y": 30, "r": 1})
mr_s.attr("transform", function(d) {"translate(" + d.x + ", " + d.y + ") rotate(" + d.r + ")"})

dur = 100
step = 10
// Lets have Mr. S go for a trip
d3.select("#Mr_Smiley")
  .transition()
  .duration(dur)
  .on("start", function repeat() {
    d3.active(this)
      .attr("transform",
        function(d)
        {
          // update y
          if (Math.random() >= .5) {
            d.y += step
          } else {
            d.y -= step
            // basic bounds
            if (d.y < 0) {
              d.y = 0
            }
          }
          // update x
          if (Math.random() >= .5) {
            d.x += step
          } else {
            d.x -= step
            if (d.x < 0) {
              d.x = 0
            }
          }
          // update r
          if (Math.random() >= .5) {
            d.r += step
          } else {
            d.r -= step
          }
          return "translate(" + d.x + ", " + d.y + ") rotate(" + d.r + ")"
        })
        .transition()
        .attr("transform",
        function(d)
        {
          // update y
          if (Math.random() >= .5) {
            d.y += step
          } else {
            d.y -= step
          }
          // update x
          if (Math.random() >= .5) {
            d.x += step
          } else {
            d.x -= step
          }
          // update r
          if (Math.random() >= .5) {
            d.r += step
          } else {
            d.r -= step
          }
          return "translate(" + d.x + ", " + d.y + ") rotate(" + d.r + ")"
        })
        .transition()
        .on("start", repeat)
        })
        
        
mr_s.on("mouseover", mouseover)
mr_s.on("mouseout", mouseout)
function mouseover(d, i) {
  var svg = d3.select("svg")
  svg.append("text").attr("id", "mouseover_text").text("god help me, this is so unsmooth").attr("x", d.x).attr("y", d.y)
}

function mouseout(d, i) {
d3.select("#mouseover_text").remove()

}
```

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%; 
  height: 100%;
}
svg {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: light-blue;
  border: 1px black solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
<h1>
Mr. Smiley goes on a trip
</h1>
```

Comment: *"appear to float"* is too vague for any programmer. You'll have to be more specific.

Comment: I think, slow down slightly before each corner, then speed up again once on the strait. Is that correct @SumNeuron?

Comment: Why the downvote? It's a good question

Comment: @GerardoFurtado I added more detail for the word "float"

Comment: @Lissy putatively, but that would require a lot of manual calibration for detecting closeness to an edge, and doesnt address deflection. Also one can increase the duration (`dur`) and step size (`step`), but then the animation between each of these transitions looks sharp

Comment: This any help? http://bl.ocks.org/explunit/6082362

Comment: @Lissy, I am not sure... that utilizes a trick for animating path drawing via stroke-offset and while one can add elements to a path in svg, I do not know if this trick would work with that

Comment: Have you seen [this example](https://bl.ocks.org/ericcitaire/5408146)?

Comment: @Mark I have not, I will try to parse out the relevant code from the game aspect. Although I am not sure if d3 force diagrams work with items outside of circles...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the simplest Mr S. bounce around a room I can code using `d3` conventions:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="d3@4.0.0" data-semver="4.0.0" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
    var w = 250,
      h = 250,
      r = 30;

    var svg = d3.select('body')
      .append('svg')
      .attr('width', w)
      .attr('height', h)
      .style('border', '1px solid steelblue');

    var ix = Math.random() * ((Math.random() > 0.5) ? 5 : -5),
      iy = Math.random() * ((Math.random() > 0.5) ? 5 : -5),
      x = w / 2,
      y = h / 2;

    var mr_s = svg.append("g")
      .attr("id", "Mr_Smiley")

    mr_s.append("circle")
      .attr("r", r)
      .style("fill", "yellow")
      .style("stroke", "black");

    mr_s.append("circle")
      .attr("cx", -10)
      .attr("cy", -10)
      .attr("r", 5)
      .style("fill", "black");

    mr_s.append("circle")
      .attr("cx", 10)
      .attr("cy", -10)
      .attr("r", 5)
      .style("fill", "black");

    mr_s.append("path")
      .attr("d", "M-10 10 A 10 10 0 0 0 10 10")
      .style("fill", "black");

    mr_s.attr('transform', 'translate(' + x + ',' + y + ')');

    d3.interval(tick, 20);

    function tick() {

      x += ix;
      y += iy;

      if (x > (w - r) || x < r) {
        ix = -ix;
      }

      if (y > (h - r) || y < r) {
        iy = -iy;
      }

      mr_s.attr('transform', 'translate(' + x + ',' + y + ')');
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```